# Node Error: Cannot find module './lib/querystring'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I keep getting the following error when trying to run

```
node ./bin/www

Error: Cannot find module './lib/querystring'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dfranc3373/Project/node_modules/request/request.js:22:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
```

No matter what I try I cannot get it to run.

I've tried to install querystring globally, I've done npm clear cache, I've set a npm link to it, and I've reinstalled npm and node and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Error is occuring here: https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L22 I suggest opening a issue on github if one doens't exist, but given the code currently in the repository, i don't see how this error could be occuring. Try uninstalling the request module and re-installing it.

Comment: *"I've tried to install querystring globally"* the built-in querystring module is not related at all to this error. There is nothing additional you can install that would make this work. The file it is requesting simply needs to exist, and it appears as though it doesn't for some unforseen reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [@KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) for help finding the solution. One of my modules did not install correctly.

First delete your node_modules folder

```
sudo rm -R ./node_modules
```

After make sure and run a `npm uninstall` on the module that has a problem (shown at `Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dfranc3373/Project/node_modules/request/request.js:22:19)`)

```
npm uninstall request
```

Then run `npm cache clean`

Finally run `npm update; npm install --save`

Comment: Hi @Dfranc3373, KevinB's solution worked amazingly. I had the same problem but with braces module. Even though the error message was "cannot find "./lib/stringify"

Just one input about the last line in your answer post - In last line, the text reads - Finally "run npm update ..." with 'run' as part of the command. And it should likely come out so that the command start with "npm update ..."

Thank you for your help. It was getting really frustrating otherwise.

Comment: Great catch! Updating now

Comment: I wish I could like this answer 20 more times