# Node & Brunch & PIXI.js on Windows, module "querystring" not found

Tags: node.js, brunch, pixi.js

I'm having troubles setting up a PIXI project on my Windows machine.

It's very easy to reproduce:

`npm install -g brunch`

`brunch new .`

`npm install --save-dev pixi.js`

Then insert `require("pixi.js")` somewhere (e.g. `initialize.js`), and

`npm run start`

Open `localhost:3333` and there's the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'querystring' from 'url/url.js'
    at require (app.js:61)
    at expanded (app.js:34)
    at app.js:147
    at url.js:104
    at url.js:737
    at initModule (app.js:42)
    at require (app.js:59)
    at expanded (app.js:34)
    at app.js:147
    at determineCrossOrigin.js:10
```

It works perfectly on a Linux machine (debian), but I always get this error on my Windows machine.

```
$ node -v
v6.9.5

$ npm -v
4.2.0

$ systeminfo | grep "OS"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
```

The troubling module is pixi. If I install and require any other module, it works fine. It also doesn't work if I install the querystring explicitly (`npm install querystring`), although it's a built-in module.

Any ideas?

Comment: No issues for me, when I tried it. Didn't give any complaint. Maybe you have "corrupted / wrong" npm modules installed. I think it might be worth to try to clear it and reinstall them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34344080/1523545

Comment: @Hachi hello, I think it's the windows issue. The abovementioned instruction works on linux perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it resolved by using bower. It's a workaround though.

`npm install -g bower`

`bower install --save pixi.js`

Then the PIXI object will be available globally out of the box. Just use it in your code.